# jQuery: Firefox doesn't show file select dialog on certain input[type=file] elements

Tags: jquery, forms, css, firefox, upload

Summary:

I have several `input[type=file]`elements all across my web app, that **do work well**.
Well, 99% of them work just fine, but just now, I ran into a case, where Firefox does not show the file select dialog when I click on said element.
I do not note any significant difference to the other circumstances, where it does work.
There's no non-clickable element over it, you even see firefoxes own button-pushed effect when clicking the element.

To make this clear, there's no "simulated click".
I'm aware this does not work at all, for security reasons.
The upload elements are encapsulated in `overflow:hidden;`-Divs, overlaying the entire content having a higher z-index and the size of the container. You do definately click the button and this worked everywhere I used this technique.

Just not in the following circumstance, and I can't seem to find the reason since 2 days.
Sorry for the inline CSS, I'll move that over into classes when the problem itself is solved.

Any hint that leads me to the cause of this problem would be *greatly* appreciated.

Uploader payload injector:

```
function _initThumbUploader()
{
// (1)
$iframe = $("<iframe />").attr(
{
    "name":     "thumb_uploader_target",
    "id":       "thumb_uploader_target",
    "class":    "upload_iframe_target"
}).css(
{
    "width":    "1px",
    "height":   "1px",
    "opacity":  "0",
    "display":  "block",
    "border":   "0px none"
});

// (2)
$uploadform = $("<form />").attr(
{
    "id":       "thumb_uploader_src",
    "method":   "post",
    "enctype":  "multipart/form-data",
    "name":     "thumb_uploader_src",
    "target":   "thumb_uploader_target",
    "action":   "/database/uploadproductpic"    
}).css(
{
    "position": "absolute",
    "left":     "0px",
    "top":      "0px",
    "opacity":  "1"
});

// (3)
$fileinput = $("<input />").attr(
{
    "class":    "upload_triggers",
    "type":     "file",
    "name":     "upthumb",
    "size":     "1",
    "accept":   "image/*"
}).css(
{
    "left":         "0px",
    "margin-left":  "-500px",
    "z-index":      "100005",
    "font-size":    "128pt",
    "position":     "absolute",
    "top":          "0px",
    "width":        "600px",
    "height":       "340px",
    "opacity":      "0",
    "cursor":       "pointer"
});

// 4
$appinput = $("<input />").attr(
{
    "name":     "app",
    "type":     "hidden",
    "value":    "products"
});

// 5
$idinput = $("<input />").attr(
{
    "name":     "productid",
    "type":     "hidden",
    "value":    "-1"
});

// Append 3, 4, 5 to 2
$uploadform.append($fileinput);
$uploadform.append($appinput);
$uploadform.append($idinput);

// Append everything to the uploader box
$(".thumbUploader").append($iframe).append($uploadform);

// Install onchange trigger
// TODO

}
```

Comment: Note1: It does work, when I manually add a **hidden** `input[type=file]` to the body tag using **Firebug**. It does **NOT**, when I do this via jQuery, *nor* when I put it static into the HTML code from since the beginning.

Comment: Any jsfiddle to let kids play?

Comment: @roasted - rough reproduction: http://jsfiddle.net/fRvRK/

Comment: But as expected, the error does not occur there. I have no clue why it doesn't work in my app. no duplicate ID or whatsoever. No script blocking access, no element laying over the input, nothing. It just does not work, until I manually add another `input[type=file]` element using **firebug** into the `<body>` area *by hand*. I despair...

Comment: BTW: Disabling all addons like adblock, firebug etc and restarting the browser makes no difference.

Comment: Ya, cannot reproduce bug in jsfiddle. Maybe you could provide direct link to your website?!

Comment: @roasted - Sadly it's in the new administration app page for a large company. It's almost done and already linked with the live DB. I'm afraid I really can not give access to that. Even if it would help you troubleshooting with me, I would most likely get killed (literally). Any ideas or known bugs? I'm really worried that it works in all other circumstances and only in this one, it does not. This is driving me insane.

Comment: I can at most provide a cropped screenshot, but I doubt this helps you... http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/931/bildschirmfoto20130524u.png

Comment: If you set a click handler to $fileinput element, is it fired?  Something like here: http://jsfiddle.net/fRvRK/1/

Comment: It does. The file select dialog still doesn't appear though.

Comment: If you don't append the iframe, still the same issue?

Comment: Yes. Plus, it doesn't matter wether I put the input element inside a form or not. **Edit:** It also makes no difference if I remove the camera-icon from the element beforehand.

Comment: I've only just noted that the form element including all sub elements is grayed out (whole text parsing is brighter) in firebug, but I believe that is, because the form has no visible elements. Setting the opacity of the input to 1 or entirely removing that css rule does not make any difference either though.

Comment: Have you tested it on an other computer? Could be relative to your OS. It's a strange issue you have

Comment: Removing the inline CSS from the script makes no difference either. Clicking it shows the click effect, but no dialog appears: http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/442/bildschirmfoto20130524u.png **Edit:** Yes, tested on OSX Snow Leopard 10.7.5 with Firefox 19, 20 and 21 as well as Windows 7 with Firefox 20 and Firefox 21

Comment: I've hacked a QND DOM-Tracker together. DOM-Path of the **Object:** `html > body > div#coreApp > div#productpage > div#productpage-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div#pthumb12 > form#thumb_uploader_src > input` - **Tracker Source Snippet:** `function _DOM_Trackr(_elem){var pathTrackr='';var $self=$(_elem).get(0);while($self && $self.tagName){var $id=($($self).attr("id"))?('#'+$($self).attr("id")):'';var $nName=$self.tagName;pathTrackr=($nName.toLowerCase())+$id+' > '+(pathTrackr);$self=$($self).parent().get(0);}alert(pathTrackr);}` (feel free to use for your own projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem solved:***

One of the parent nodes of said input field (see DOM Tree):

`html > body > div#coreApp >`****(div#productpage)****`> div#productpage-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div#pthumb12 > form#thumb_uploader_src > input`

***had*** the following jQuery click event assigned:

```
/* ... */
$elem.click(function(e){
    if (e.target !== this) { return false; }
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

This caused firefox to not react on the file input anymore.

I'll leave this here in case anyone else is running into this problem as it took me 3 days to reverse.

Thanks everyone for your time, especially a big thanks to @roasted

Comment: **Line changed to:** `if ((e.target !== this) && ($(e).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() != "input")) { return false; }` - works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be due to a recent reconfiguring of the input [type="file"] in FF22 and 23, and it's unrelated to jQuery. The FF devs have decided to do without the input boxes and now display a simple text message beside the Browse... button. I can't see what it is they are trying to fix with this, but it is now a problem when your form has a dark background - if your font colour works against a standard/default white form input background-color, it may become invisible (or appear 'broken', because it is low-contrast) when used for text outside the box. Potentially, this might leave us needing to target this kind of input with a rule for just the recent versions of this browser, but an easier solution is to define the background-color for all inputs, even if that's the default white:

```
input {background-color: #FFF}
```

in your CSS. I've proposed that this should now become part of normalise.css, but I'm really hoping that the FF devs put a BG of white in as default - that'll make the text visible, at least. Much better still, revert to as was - it wasn't broken!